# Get last rows where value is 0

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.3

I have a table **pesajes** where the weigh-ins of the competitors are stored

**pesajes:**

```
id  championship   competitor   accepted     time
1       18           1280          0      1370931202  
2       18           1280          1      1370931784 
3       18           1203          0      1370932502  
4       18           870           1      1370934905  
5       18           1203          0      1370961212
6       18           1100          0      1370984288
```

I want to select only the rows where the last weigh-in was 0 (accepted is 0), for example: In this case I want to return only the rows 5 and 6

I was using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM pesajes WHERE championship=18 and accepted=0 GROUP by id
```

Obviously this query does not work because, among other problems, it returns the row 1 and I do not want that row because the last weigh-in of the competitor 1280 is accepted.
How could I solve it?

Comment: So, you only want those distinct which only have `accepted = 0` (So no record of the same competitor and championship with `accepted = 1`), the last of each competitor, right? What version of Mysql are you using?

Comment: So, you want to get the last row for each competitor (where `accepted = 0`)?

Comment: Yes, I only need the last row of each competitor only if that last row has accepted = 0.  I'm using 10.3.34-MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much, you need:

- The last record of each competitor with `accepted = 0`
- Only those competitors that do not have another record with `accepted = 1`

Other answers use `time`, so I provide an alternative without using that column. I decided to do this since you don't mention it at all, so I don't know how reliable it could be for what you need.

```sql
SELECT p.* 
FROM pesajes p
    JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(id) AS id, SUM(accepted) AS criteria
        FROM pesajes 
        GROUP BY championship, competitor
    ) filter ON filter.id = p.id AND filter.criteria = 0;
```

This will work in MySQL 5.5 up to 8.0.

And [here is the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c3f582ac2a0e45beadd57c1bb6c42967).

Answer (score 1):

Your question falls into the category of retrieving the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) rows. Beginning with MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10.2, you can use a partitioning non-aggregating [Window Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html):

```
WITH tmp AS (
    SELECT p.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY competitor ORDER BY accepted DESC, id DESC) AS rn
        FROM pesajes AS p
)
SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE accepted = 0 AND rn = 1;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT p.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY competitor ORDER BY accepted DESC, id DESC) AS rn
        FROM pesajes AS p
) as tmp
WHERE accepted = 0 AND rn = 1;
```

These queries create a partition for each competitor, ordered by `accepted`, then `id`. Finally, only the first (`order by id` with `rn=1`) rows are returned which "still" have `accepted=0`.

If you want those *last* (ordered by `id`) rows where `accepted=0`, and it doesn't matter that one of the competitors already had an `accepted=1` row, just remove the `ORDER BY accepted`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT p.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY competitor ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
        FROM pesajes AS p
) as tmp
WHERE accepted = 0 AND rn = 1;
```

This would create a partition table, partitioned by `competitor`, ordered by `id` and selects each partition's first row (`WHERE rn=1`) where that row has `accepted=0`.

Comment: I did a test and this query worked correctly for me. But @Jetto query was running faster in tests. Anyway thanks for the solution!

Comment: @Nebur81 You wrote, you want to consider also competitors who have `accepted=1` - if it's not the last record. That stands in conflict with Jettos second bullet point (and that solution works only for tables with an ID column, but this is the case here).

Answer (score 0):

Query -

```
select * from champ c1 inner join 
(select competitor, max(time_1) mtime from champ
group by competitor) c2
where c1.competitor = c2.competitor
and c1.time_1 >= c2.mtime
and c1.accepted = 0
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4801c4e5751b1ac85e99abcfe7ded631)